# Binding to Object property inside List inside Object

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

I am trying to bind the RectangleContour.ValueDistance.Value to a datagridview. My code is as follows

```
        public class RectangleContour
        {
        public ObservableCollection<ValueDistance> valuedistancelist = new ObservableCollection<ValueDistance>();

        public ObservableCollection<ValueDistance> ValueDistanceList
        {
            get { return valuedistancelist; }
        }

        public int Name { get; set; }
        public Rectangle RectangleData { get; set; }
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public double Val1 { get; set; }
        public double Val2 { get; set; }
        public double Val3 { get; set; }
        public double Val1Dist { get; set; }
        public double Val2Dist { get; set; }
        public double Val3Dist { get; set; }
        public bool Visible { get; set; }
        }

        public class ValueDistance
        {
        public double value { get; set; }
        public double distance { get; set; }

        public double Value
        {
            get { return value; }
        }

        public double Distance
        {
            get { return distance; }
        }
        }
```

I can bind successfully to the Val1 or Val1Dist properties of rectangle contour but I want to be able to account for n ValueDistance pairs, so I thought a collection would be a better way of doing it, any ideas why I cant bind properly the Value and Distance properties through my RectangleContour class? Any help is greatly appreciated as always.

Edit: Apologies, to be more precise it seems like I cannot 'reach' the Value or Distance properties through ContourControl, the datagridcolumn just shows these values as blank and they cannot be edited in the grid like the Val1 and Val1Dist values can.

Comment: What does it mean you "can't bind"? Please be more precise. Show how you fill the ValueDistanceList, and how your relevant XAML (with the bindings) looks like.

Comment: check for binding errors in the output window

Comment: You won't be able to change those properties in the grid, because they don't have a public setter defined